# Glyhpicon loading time causes shaking

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm trying to fix my glyphicons. Whenever the page is loaded they move and appear after a very short time, but my navigation is shaking because of that.

Does anyone have a fix or expirience with this?

Below is the code how I load the fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format("woff2"), url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format("woff"), url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format("truetype"), url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format("svg")
}
```

Comment: please make jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a problem with loading the icons, I would suggest trying to load them via the bootstrap CDN to see if that makes any difference:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Apart from that "jumping" sounds like you don't set a fixed width to the icon, so if you do that, the jumping should be solved in any case.